# Splitting a string in an array of strings of limited size

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm, data-structures

I have a string of a random address like

> `String s = "H.N.-13/1443 laal street near bharath dental lab near thana qutubsher near modern bakery saharanpur uttar pradesh 247001";`

I want to split it into array of string with two conditions:

- each element of that array of string is of length less than or equal to 20
- No awkward ending of an element of array of string

For example, splitting every 20 characters would produce:

```
"H.N.-13/1443 laal st"
"reet near bharath de"
"ntal lab near thana"
"qutubsher near moder"
"n bakery saharanpur"
```

but the correct output would be:

```
"H.N.-13/1443 laal"
"street near bharath"
"dental lab near"
"thana qutubsher near"
"modern bakery"
"saharanpur"
```

Notice how each element in string array is less than or equal to 20.

The above is my output for this code:

```java
static String[] split(String s,int max){
    int total_lines = s.length () / 24;
    if (s.length () % 24 != 0) {
        total_lines++;
    }

    String[] ans = new String[total_lines];
    int count = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < total_lines; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            if (ans[count] == null) {
                ans[count] = "";
            }

            if (count > 0) {
                if ((20 * count) + j < s.length()) {
                    ans[count] += s.charAt (20 * count + j);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                ans[count] += s.charAt (j);
            }
        }

        String a = "";

        a += ans[count].charAt (0);

        if (a.equals (" ")) {
            ans[i] = ans[i].substring (0, 0) + "" + ans[i].substring (1);
        }

        System.out.println (ans[i]);

        count++;
    }
    return ans;
}

public static void main (String[]args) {
    String add = "H.N.-13/1663 laal street near bharath dental lab near thana qutubsher near modern bakery";
    String city = "saharanpur";
    String state = "uttar pradesh";
    String zip = "247001";
    String s = add + " " + city + " " + state + " " + zip;
    String[]ans = split (s);
}
```

Comment: Is your code generating the wrong or the correct output? What exactly is the question?

Comment: it was generating the wrong output,now it is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all occurrences of up to 20 chars starting with a non-space and ending with a word boundary, and collect them to a List:

```java
List<String> parts = Pattern.compile("\\S.{1,19}\\b").matcher(s)
  .results()
  .map(MatchResult::group)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/yh9GYq).

Comment: yes i resolved this problem yesterday by this similar approach by first splitting inital String into a String array and then adding each element into arraylist but my code is obviously not as clean as you.

Comment: Also i am trying your code on intellij IDE and it is not able to capture results(),group.

Comment: @umar `results()` returns a `Stream<MatchResult>`. What do you mean exactly by "can't capture results().group"? I don't know what error/problem you're having, but it could be you're using a very old version of Java; try upgrading to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

The code is not very clear, but at first glance it seems you are building character by character that is why you are getting the output you see. Instead you go word by word if you want to retain a word and overflow it to next String if necessary. A more promising code would be:

```
static String[] splitString(String s, int max) {
    String[] words = s.split("\s+");
    List<String> out = new ArrayList<>();
    int numWords = words.length;
    int i = 0;
    while (i <numWords) {
        int len = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (i < numWords && len < max) {
            int wordLength = words[i].length();
            len += (i == numWords-1 ? wordLength : wordLength + 1);//1 for space
            if (len <= max) {
                sb.append(words[i]+ " ");
                i++;
            }
        }
        out.add(sb.toString().trim());
    }
    return out.toArray(new String[] {});
        
}
```

Note: It works on your example input, but you may need to tweak it so it works for cases like a long word containing more than 20 characters, etc.

Comment: I'd say that the spaces should be included in the length. If you'd only add space at the start of a new word then you can just use the size of `StringBuilder` (which in turn, could be initialized to capacity of 20).

Comment: I modified the code to include space in length.

Comment: yeah i took similar approach of taking word by word instead of character.                                                                    ArrayList<String> ans=new ArrayList<>();
        String str="";
            for(int j=0;j<sp.length;j++){

               if(str.length()+sp[j].length()<=255)
               {
                   str+=" " +sp[j];
               }
               else{
                   ans.add(str);
                   j--;
                   str="";
               }
            }
            ans.add(str)